# Codeception looking for external server

Tags: yii, codeception

I finally handled that [Yii1](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii1.html) and [YiiBridge](https://github.com/Codeception/YiiBridge) install instructions and run some sample test. The problem now is, instead use my localhost, PHPBrowser is going to an unknown server from LAN, which obviously fails all tests. Is there any configuration that can prevent this?

edit: Refs

https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Yii1.html

https://github.com/Codeception/YiiBridge

Comment: please add complete info what address it points to ?

Comment: Added addresses